Pandas time series split shows gaps
I am splitting a continuous timeseries (powerconsumption by the hour) into train/val/test but see unexpected gaps in the split dataframes. What might be the cause?
train_split_end = round(len(df) * (1 - val_ratio))
val_split_end = len(df)

train = df.iloc[:train_split_end]
val = df.iloc[train_split_end:val_split_end]

The splits themselves are contiguous
train.index[-1]
Out[26]: Timestamp('2014-07-26 23:00:00')
val.index[0]
Out[27]: Timestamp('2014-07-27 00:00:00')

But the plots show gaps inside of each train['MW'].plot() and val['MW'].plot() set which are not present in the original df.
The dataset is https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption - AEP_hourly.csv
Thanks for suggestions!



the first screenshot is the plot of both dfs? provide the code related to plotting the dfs as well

What is val_ratio?

@mozway The val ratio is 0.15. such that len(train)-> 103082, len(val) -> 18191, len(val)/(len(train) + len(val)) -> 0.15

I dont seem to be getting the gap on my end. You might want to try sklearns train/test split method. To do this we begin by importing the necessary package and read in the dataset.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('AEP_hourly.csv', index_col=[0])

The next step is to split the data into a train and test set. The random state value is simply used so that the results can be reproducible. You can read more about the parameters at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html. The test size here has been set to 20% of the dataframe.
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

If you want to further split the train and test to include a validation set, then you can repeat the above step on the training dataset. The following will take another 20% from the training set to create another validation set.
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(X_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

You can then check the size of each set using X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape
Hope this helps.

The train_test split does random splitting. Since this is a time-series I am going for contiguous chunks - predict future consumption based on past values.

there is a parameter inside train_test_split(X_train, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=42). this should take care of the issue.

Random state just makes results reproducible. It will still sample data as e.g. timepoints train=1, 2, 5, 7, 3,9 test=8,3,4. For time series, contiguous, ordered chunks are needed like train=[1,2,3,4,5,6] val=[7,8,9]. The issue (per my answer above) seems to be that train = df.iloc[:train_split_end] when applied to a df with datetimeindex does not get the first train_split_end entries, as one might expect - the order is not guaranteed.

Date index in pandas does not appear to be consecutive in the sense that of iloc. Grabbing dates with:
train = df.iloc[:train_split_end]
val = df.iloc[train_split_end:val_split_end]

Yields non-contiguous chunks resulting in mixing of the train-val splits which is seen as the gaps on the plot. It is necessary to split by actual date:
train_split_end = 1 - val_ratio
val_split_end = 1

train_split_end_date = (df.index.min() + ((df.index.max() - df.index.min()) * train_split_end))
train = df[df.index <= train_split_end_date]
val_split_end_date = (df.index.min() + ((df.index.max() - df.index.min()) * val_split_end))
val = df[(df.index > train_split_end_date) & (df.index <= val_split_end_date)]

